# JSON code for hiding a "See More" button in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, json

Can anyone help me in hiding a class "ReactFieldEditor-MoreToggle" button in SharePoint list?

Comment: Hiding elements by CSS class or any other manipulation of the page DOM of modern pages is strongly discouraged by Microsoft. It is one of the reasons that Microsoft does not have modern Script Editor or Content Editor web parts.

If you could explain the business reason for hiding the button, maybe someone could suggest a supported way to achieve the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure of which portion of the UI you are referring to, so here are a couple of solutions:

If you are referring to the auto-truncation that occurs on multi-text fields with lots of text:
[image]

This can be removed by applying the following format (Column Settings -> Format this column -> Advanced Mode):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

[image]

---

If instead you are referring to the `See all` link using in the list/library webpart:

[image]

This can removed by toggling the Show/Hide "See all" Button toggle in the webpart property pane:

[image]

---

If you are referring to the `See more` link in a list item form for multi-text fields with lots of content:

[image]

Applying the format from above will ensure all your text is seen in the form. Unfortunately, however, it will NOT remove the link even if it is useless at this point:

[image]

There is currently no *supported* way to remove this link from the list form without customizing the list form in Power Apps (and soon SPFx).